# Get list of all installed software in each Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, linux, virtual-machine, disk-space, vmware-workstation

To manage my all `virtual machines`, I have purchased VMWare infrastructure but one thing I need eagerly is having:

- status of machine,
- a list of installed software and
- `disk usage`

for each virtual machines. Status (Running/Stop etc.) is provided by VMWare but not a list of installed software. Some of my VMs are windows and some of are Linux too. I can develop applications but don’t know how to get these details from each Virtual machine.

Comment: @nutsch: Thank you for the nice editing and representation......

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like IT Assets Management.  I've used a bunch of "Enterprise" versions. IE expen$ive. But I've heard good things about Spiceworks.